# How can I replace DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOR for `group_vars` in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Ansible 2.10.1 provides the following deprecation warning:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR option, This feature is fragile
and not portable, leading to continual confusion and misuse , use the ``combine``
filter explicitly instead. This feature will be removed in version 2.13.
```

I am currently using this setting to manage how `group_vars` and `host_vars` are implicitly merged. So I am wondering how I can do something "explicitly" for an *implicit* loading of variables? Is there another more specific ansible setting that can be used for this particular merging? Or does this mean that I cannot rely on `group_vars` and `host_vars` being implicitly loaded at all, and that I have to explicitly perform the inclusion and merging of those vars myself? Or is there some other way still of achieving non-default hash behavior for ansible's handy autoloading of `group_vars`?

Comment: You'll have to explicitly perform the inclusion and merging of those vars. Are you going to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) use-case?

Comment: OK thanks Vladamir, that certainly makes autoloading of variables a less useful feature, and that answers the question about the implicit case. It's a shame, because the option that was removed for being "confusing" is far more obvious to me than the code required to replace it.

As for a more specific use-case, I understand how to achieve this explicitly for anything I might need to do, and your explanation below seems great for those that don't, so thanks for that as well.

Comment: You're welcome, Jeffrey. See [group_vars best practices](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/FIwvKTwxqiA/m/FAuYfYC2reYJ). This problem was discussed by the developers.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: *"How can I replace [DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-hash-behaviour) for `group_vars` in Ansible?"*

A: The deprecation warning says: *"use the combine filter"*. The details depend on the use-case. For example, let's have the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[grp001]
srv001

[grp002]
srv002

[grp003]
srv001
srv002
```

the group_vars

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/grp001.yml 
test_var:
    x: grp001
    y: grp001

shell> cat group_vars/grp002.yml 
test_var:
    x: grp002
    z: grp002

shell> cat group_vars/grp003.yml 
test_var:
    x: grp003
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: srv001,srv002
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

The default behavior is to **replace** the variables

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

ok: [srv001] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003"
    }
}
ok: [srv002] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003"
    }
}
```

Optionally, the dictionaries can be **merged**

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_HASH_BEHAVIOUR=merge ansible-playbook pb.yml

ok: [srv001] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003",
        "y": "grp001"
    }
}
ok: [srv002] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003",
        "z": "grp002"
    }
}
```

---

Without DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOR available (deprecated in 2.13) *"use the combine filter"*. For example, use [group_names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) to include the variables and **explicitly** combine the dictionaries

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: srv001,srv002
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "group_vars/{{ item }}.yml"
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ group_names }}"
    - set_fact:
        test_var: "{{ test_var|default({})|combine(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ group_names|
                map('extract', hostvars[inventory_hostname], 'test_var')|
                list }}"
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

ok: [srv002] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003",
        "z": "grp002"
    }
}
ok: [srv001] => {
    "test_var": {
        "x": "grp003",
        "y": "grp001"
    }
}
```

---

References

- [Merging dictionaries for "environment" parameter](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/WJzosC1jERU)
- [ansible_merge_vars: An action plugin for Ansible](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-merge-vars/)
- [Thinking outside the box with Ansible](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/thinking-outside-the-box-with-ansible/)

Comment: I do understand how to use the combine filter explicitly, and this is a nice explanation of it. My question is how to achieve non-default hash behavior for the *implicit* loading of group_vars. I'll try to update my question to try to be clearer.

Comment: It's clear enough. There will be no implicit merging with 2.13 and beyond.

Comment: The unclear part is if there will still be any (explicit) way to control hash behavior during implicit loading. Without such control implicit loading is limited, and yes, having to explicitly load group vars is surprisingly less elegant and less useful, to me at least.

Comment: I'm also extremely interested in this. We are using merging *everywhere* in our playbooks. This change means we have to rewrite (and audit!) couple years of work. Not nice :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else late to the party who's seeing the deprecation warning but not seeing `DEFAULT_HASH_BEHAVIOUR` in their code...

It turns out I had `hash_behaviour = merge` in my (inherited) config.